Do essential singularities require periodicity in complex functions?
I have this doubt after reading Picard's Great Theorem, which states that near an essential singularity, a function takes all complex values, with at most one exception, infinitely often. This seems to suggest some kind of "repetition" or periodic-like behavior. However, I am wondering if essential singularities can also occur in non-periodic functions.
Is it necessary for a function to be periodic in order to have an essential singularity? In other words, can non-periodic functions also have essential singularities, or are essential singularities inherently tied to periodicity?

$\exp(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ and is not periodic.

Every entire function has an essential singularity at $z=\infty$, and “most” of them are not periodic.

ok, so does it mean function oscillates wildly near essential singularity and they do not repeat their value in a periodic way?

Essential singularities and periodicity are unrelated. Note that if $z_n \to a \in \Bbb C$ and $f(z_n) = w$ then it is impossible that $(z_n)$ is periodic.

Thank you for clearing up my confusion.
